# Passing variable to layout template in Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am trying to set the refresh rate of a status page using a stash variable
So I have the following code in the controller to render the page:

```
my $refreshrate = 10;
$self->stash( refreshrate => $refreshrate);
$self->render();
```

in the html template I have:

```
% layout 'refreshLayout', title => 'A title';
% content_for refresh => begin
% end
<div>....body content .../<div>
```

and in the layout template I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%= refreshrate %>"/>
        .....
    <title><%= title %></title>
 </head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

I always end up with a page rendered with no value in the content attribute of the refresh meta tag.
It looks like the `refreshrate` replacement does not work.
However both the `content` and `title` replacements do work.

So what am I doing wrong here?
And while we are here,  why in the layout template do we do use <%= content %> (and not $content)
While in the template of the regular page we use the more logical <%= $variable %>
How does the replacement work in the layout template versus the replacement in the template of the main page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stash values appear as perl variables in your templates. (`title` is special as it's also a default helper function).
If you want to pass the stash value for refreshrate to the layout, you have to add it to your `layout()` args:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' =>  sub  {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->stash (refreshrate => 10),
    $c->render(template => 'foo/bar')};

app->start;
__DATA__

@@ foo/bar.html.ep
% layout 'mylayout', title => 'Hi there',refreshrate => $refreshrate;
Hello World!

@@ layouts/mylayout.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<%= $refreshrate %>"/>
    <title><%= $title %></title></head>
  <body><%= content %></body>
</html>
```

See **Layouts** in [Rendering doc](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering)